# Do you need to know Gatling Laser plan before getting the Ultracite version?

Tags: fallout-76

I've been trying to get the plan for the Ultracite Gatling Laser for weeks now: I've been killing the Scorchebeast Queen, doing random events in the Cranberry Bog - no luck. I have tons of various plans for Ultracite mods, but not a plan how to make the UTGL.

But then I've noticed on the Fallout Wiki, that the regular Gatling Laser (that you can learn from Modus) has an option to put a Prime Receiver, which will deal extra damage to Scorched, like all Ultracite weapons.

So I am confused here: do you need to know the plan for regular Gatling Laser before you can get the plan for the Ultracite version? Or is the UTC version a regular laser with a different receiver?